# How to set emoji by using unicode in EmojiAppCompatTextView

Tags: android, android-layout, unicode

I need to show country flag by using emoji, I am using following website to get flags unicode.

https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/iso3166

I am using `androidx.emoji.widget.EmojiAppCompatTextView` to display flags.

But when i use `unicode` it does not print the flag.

```
emojiCountryFlag.setText("US") //Print UN
```

**or**

`emojiCountryFlag.setText("U+1F1FA U+1F1F8")` //Prints same in output

But if i use `emojiCountryFlag.setText("\uD83C\uDDFA\uD83C\uDDEC")`, it prints the perfect flag.

I am unable to understand how to print flag by using unicode, or is there any place i can get this type of string `"\uD83C\uDDFA\uD83C\uDDEC".`

Android studio generates this code when i print `ISO`value in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it on the same page as you looked. `U+1F1FA U+1F1F8` are the unicode symbols used to identify the flag. `\uD83C\uDDFA\uD83C\uDDEC` are the surrogates you'd need to use with *Java* and *Android*.

```
        Code    UTF‑8                           Surrogates
    1F1FA   F0 9F 87 BA     3C D8 FA DD     D83C DDFA   REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER U
    1F1F8   F0 9F 87 B8     3C D8 F8 DD     D83C DDF8   REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER S
```

To simply your task, you could just paste the unicode flags within *Android Studio*.

https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect/hex/1F1FA/1F1F8

Comment: Hey @tynn, Thanks for the answer, yes i am able to generate these codes when i paste them on android studio, but i will be getting these emojis from server, and i need to tell them what type of code they need to send me to generate these emojis.

Comment: Easiest might be to just send the strings as UTF-8.